# Uv Island Not Straight

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding UV unwrapping and I've created my mesh and I think I've marked all the right seams but for some reason the UV Island isn't straight.

[image]

Can somebody help me understand what's going on? Also additionally I don't know if it's possible to have a island stay on the map without having to have the faces selected or showing any other parts of the model if so how would I do that?

Comment: To add to unwave's answer, you can orthogonalize the UVs with the UV Squares addon

Comment: @moonboots `UV Squares` worked well only if the topology is a grid. With the topology in the subject one would need some pinning and hiding trickery. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXocgeouVWY Otherwise you will get overlaps and split UVs.

Comment: Oh ok.....................   ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the UVs by `Projecting from View` while being in the orthogonal view, pin the outer border and then unwrap again and try to use `Conformal` method in the `F9` redo panel.

Can also just pin the borders enable `Live Unwrap` and straiten them manually with `S`+`X`or`Y`+`0`

For buildings `Cube Projection` could suffice.

Comment: About the additional part: there is `UV Sync Selection` but it is situational.